# Why cloning an RDS cluster is faster and more space efficient than snapc

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I want to create a Duplicate (clone) of an Aurora DB cluster.

Both the source and the copy are in the same region and are both for dev purposes .

Both are MySql.

I want to access each cluster via a different url .

Reading about  [Copy-on-write protocol for Aurora cloning.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html#Aurora.Managing.Clone.Protocol)
and [SQL snapshot](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-snapshot-in-sql-server/)

The aws docs state that :"Creating a clone is faster and more space-efficient than physically copying the data using a different technique such as restoring a snapshot." ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html#Aurora.Managing.Clone.Console))

Yet , I don't quite understand why using a snapshot is an inferior solution  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot is slower, because first [snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshotCluster.html) copies **entire db storage**:

> The amount of time it takes to create a DB cluster snapshot varies with the size your databases. Since the snapshot includes the **entire storage volume**, the size of files, such as temporary files, also affects the amount of time it takes to create the snapshot.

So if you database has, lets say 100GB, the first snapshot of it will require copying 100 GBs. This operation can take time.

In contrast, when you clone, there is **no copy** done at first. Both original and the new database use **same storage**. Only when a write operation is performed, they start to diverge.